# How to list all the files used during Linux boot

Tags: linux, rhel, boot

I would like to get the list of files that are used during the process of Linux boot. We are developing the protected enterprise system based on the RHEL 6.4. The integrity of specified files will be checked by a special hardware.

So the question is - how to get the list of these files (with resolved dependencies coming from different booting services and daemons).

Comment: Maybe you can use find with atime option. But... if you want such thing then you should know what is your system doing. You can always raise a question directly to Red Hat.

Comment: I was solving similar issue on OpenBSD and I discover that I need master.passwd (shadow on Linux) file as well, as single user boot can ask for root password before getting you shell. That said... you have to know all details how system boots with all possibilities.

Comment: Access time is no proper solution to this. You should leave this task to the Kernel, as that's the only facility in (non-systemd) systems which is capable of really tracking all opened files.

Comment: First, define what you want "boot" to encompass. Is it just loading the kernel and mounting rootfs? Then initramfs and whatever grub uses will be all you need to look at. Is it everything up until the login prompt? Everything until the X login screen? There may be some sort of early-boot systemtap available, but if not, you'll probably have to run the system on a VM or a kernel debugger to see every file it accesses.

Comment: Your answer made me think deeply. I really do not have a clear understanding of what is called the "boot" and when does it stop. As we are speaking about servers without X.org, so probably boot finishes when we see the login prompt.

Comment: Would [auditing](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/auditd8.html) be an option or will that start too late during boot?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve in reality? If you want to have secure boot you either boot from network (root on nfs) or from a read-only media but then you would need modified RHEL...

Comment: We have Red Hat Enterprise Virtualisation environment as a base of our system. Desktops are thin clients (without hard disks) which recieve the boot image of the operating system  on every power up. After boot thin clients provide access to the virtual machines being executed by Hypervisor. So actually the question is how to check the integrity of Hypervisor. As any computer, it is ought to boot too :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to RHEL support, the clear solution has been discovered. It is based on systemtap kernel module usage. Quoted from [here](http://vitalyisaev2.blogspot.ru/2013/12/determination-of-files-used-during.html) to avoid link rot. And thank you again for all of your advice :)

I could not even imagine that systemtap is able to start even before the init script and track the booting process. I very appreciate the [Red Hat](http://www.linkedin.com/company/red-hat?trk=cp_followed_name_red-hat) [Support](https://www.facebook.com/redhatjobs) and personally Pushpendra Chavan for help with this perfect tool (unfortunately I don't know developers this method belongs to exactly - otherwise I'd credit them in the first place).

So we need to create two simple scripts:

`bootinit.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh


# Use tmpfs to collect data
/bin/echo "Mounting tmpfs to /tmp/stap/data"
/bin/mount -n -t tmpfs -o size=40M none /tmp/stap/data

# Start systemtap daemon & probe
/bin/echo "Loading bootprobe2.ko in the background. Pid is :"
/usr/bin/staprun \
    /root/bootprobe2.ko \
    -o /root/bootprobe2.log -D

# Give daemon time to start collecting...
/bin/echo "Sleeping a bit.."
sleep 5

# Hand off to real init
/bin/echo "Starting."
exec /sbin/init 3
```

and `bootprobe2.1.stp` written in embedded systemtap scripting language:

```
global ident

function get_usertime:long() {
  return task_utime() + @cast(task_current(), "task_struct", "kernel<linux/sched.h>")->signal->utime;
}

function get_systime:long() {
 return task_stime() + @cast(task_current(), "task_struct", "kernel<linux/sched.h>")->signal->stime;
}

function timestamp() {
  return sprintf("%d %s", gettimeofday_s(), ident[pid()])
}

function proc() {
  return sprintf("%d \(%s\)", pid(), execname())
}  

function push(pid, ppid) {
   ident[ppid] = indent(1)
   ident[pid] = sprintf("%s", ident[ppid])
}

function pop(pid) {
  delete ident[pid]
} 

probe syscall.fork.return {
  ret = $return
  printf("%s %s forks %d  \n", timestamp(), proc(), ret)
  push(ret, pid())
}

probe syscall.execve {
  printf("%s %s execs %s \n", timestamp(), proc(), filename)
}

probe syscall.open {
  if ($flags & 1) {
    printf("%s %s writes %s \n", timestamp(), proc(), filename)
  } else {
    printf("%s %s reads %s \n", timestamp(), proc(), filename)
  }
} 

probe syscall.exit {
  printf("%s %s exit with user %d sys %d \n", timestamp(), proc(), get_usertime(), get_systime())
  pop(pid())
}
<linux sched.h=""><linux sched.h="">
</linux></linux>
```

In order to receive the list of files accessed during the booting process in systemtap log format we should implement the following:

Download and install the PROPERLY named versions of `systemtap` and `kernel debuginfo` packages (I have been given [this link](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html-single/SystemTap_Beginners_Guide/index.html), but you'd better use [this](http://www.emsperformance.net/2013/02/27/installing-systemtap-on-centos-6/) if you're on CentOS);

Create `/tmp/stap` and `/tmp/stap/data`

```
mkdir -p /tmp/stap/data
```

Place `bootprobe2.1.stp` and `bootinit.sh` into `/root` and make them executable: 
    chmod +x /root/boot*

Edit `bootinit.sh` and change 'exec /sbin/init 3' to 'exec /sbin/init 5' if 5 is your default runlevel.

Create the .ko module from bootprobe2.stp

```
 cd /root
 stap bootprobe2.1.stp -m bootprobe2 -p4
```

Reboot.

Halt `grub` (press Esc or Shift) and press 'a' on the default kernel. At the end of the kernel line enter the following and press enter:

```
init=/root/bootinit.sh,
```

Normal boot will resume. After logging in, `kill` the `stapio` process, copy `bootprobe2.log` out of the `tmpfs` `/tmp/stap/data` directory and unmount it.

```
killall stapio
cp /tmp/stap/data/bootprobe2.log /tmp/stap/
umount /tmp/stap/data
```

Now check the file `/tmp/stap/bootprobe2.log` file for the list of all files which are read during boot.

Answer (score 7):

Set up the [audit subsystem](http://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/audit/) to record calls to `open`.

```
auditctl -a exit,always -S open,openat,creat,execve
```

Do that from the initramfs, so that the rule is in place when the main system (`/sbin/init` on the real root filesystem) starts.

Note that what you're proposing to do won't bring any real security on a typical setup. Anyone who can replace these files by other versions has root access and can also feed bogus data to the logging system.

If the boot media is protected externally so that root cannot modify it (e.g. because it's read-only or under the exclusive control of a secure bootloader), and if loading kernel modules is blocked, then measuring the files can be reliable if it's done right. However, if all you're doing with the measures is comparing them with reference values, this is more difficult and less effective than using an integrity-protected root filesystem (i.e. in practice on dmcrypt, with Trusted Grub for the bootloader).

Comment: You may want to log `openat` and `execve` as well (at least). Now it also depends what is meant by _used_ and _file_, as it may be that you also need to log `creat`, `truncate`, `access`, `stat`, `mkdir`, `connect`...

Comment: Could you please provide some additional explanations to the methods you have mentioned? Where this line of code should be placed? Should I unzip the /boot/initramfs-xxxxx.img reconfigure it and put it back to /boot as archieve?

Comment: @VitalyIsaev I don't know Redhat's initramfs structure. If it's anything like Debian, you would add a script somewhere under `/usr/share/initramfs-tools` (the path may be different on RH), then rebuild the initramfs (on Debian it's `update-initramfs`) and reboot.

Answer (score 1):

A good starting place would be `/etc/rci.d` where `i` is a number representing the runlevel you're booting into. For example, if your server is headless, `i` will typically be 3. Looking under `/etc/rc3.d` will show what services are being started when you boot into runlevel 3.

Comment: Thank you! But what are the further steps? How can I track the activity of the services specified in /etc/rc.d (= get the list of files accessed by them)?

Comment: RHEL6 is upstart based too...

Comment: @JiriXichtkniha Please correct me if I'm wrong, but don't `upstart`-based init systems use the `/etc/rci.d` directory scheme as well?

Comment: Yes they have legacy compatibility as they have "hook" to call SysV scripts :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `atime` is enabled for your root and boot filesystems in your kernel (or that `noatime` is not set), then after booting you can use `stat` to check the access time for every file and see which ones were accessed during boot.

Comment: Could you please explain, how can I do that? My fstab has no **noatime** option but access time still is not written to system files metadata